# numpy hstack: How to find the correct dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to stack two numpy arrays together.

The first has dimensions `(1797, 64)` and the second has dimensions `(1797,)`. I want to create an array with dimensions `(1797, 65)`. This should be possible through `np.hstack()`:

```
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np

digits = datasets.load_digits(n_class=10)
data = np.array(digits.data)
labels = np.array(digits.target)
myData = np.hstack((data, labels[:,None]))

print(data)
print(labels)
print(myData)
```

However, when you run the code given above, you will see that `data` and the first 64 columns of `myData` are not equal. Can somebody explain to me what is going on?

Comment: Running `myData[:,:64].all() == data.all()` yields `true`. Are you sure that you are not just confused by the display of the array that hides some lines and columns ?

Comment: That is definitely not doing what you think @Lescurel, the way to do this is `np.allclose(myData[:,:64], data)`

Comment: @yatu thank you, you're right. `np.allclose(myData[:,:64], data)` also yields true though. @Luk, Are you sure that you are not just confused by the display of the array that hides some lines and columns ?

Comment: hey, thx guys! Actually, I was confused by the display.